# Como mostrar lista de amigos do Facebook em ios com Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para mostrar uma lista com meus amigos do facebook utilizando o SDK do facebook para IOS e com Swift. Já fiz a instalação e já estou me logando pelo facebook. Só não estou conseguindo mostrar minha lista de amigos.

Comment: Você já está realizando o login do usuário no aplicativo ou a dúvida envolve todo o processo (que é um pouco longo), incluindo instalação do SDK?

Comment: Já fiz a instalação e já estou me logando pelo facebook. Só não estou conseguindo mostrar minha lista de amigos.

Comment: Votei para reabrir, mas talvez você possa colocar esses detalhes na própria pergunta, basta [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/63908/edit), assim pode ser que entendam que não está amplo demais.

Comment: Reajustes feitos

Comment: Se você já tem algum código que tentou fazer funcionar mas não conseguiu é sempre válido também.

Comment: Não tenho Otávio, vi alguns exemplos e OC mais não consegui fazer nada parecido em swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir do [**Graph API 2.0**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog), a lista completa de amigos não é mais permitida por padrão na autenticação e somente retorna os amigos que autorizaram, ou seja, aqueles que possuem também seu aplicativo.

Então, antes de mais nada você precisa pedir permissão ao usuário assim que você realizar a autenticação. Basta a chave adequada para tal:

> user_friends

Com esta permissão aceita pelo usuário, você pode então fazer a requisição:

```
var friendsRequest : FBRequest = FBRequest.requestForMyFriends()
friendsRequest.startWithCompletionHandler{(connection:FBRequestConnection!, result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
    var resultdict = result as NSDictionary
    var friends = resultdict.objectForKey("data") as NSArray
}
```

Com isso, você vai possuir no vetor `friends` a lista de amigos, e então é só montar a sua lista de amigos.

[Nesta resposta do *SOen*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23417628/1216394) tem algumas alternativas para buscar todos os amigos, independente se o amigo possui ou não seu aplicativo, que é baseada em utilizar os *endpoints* `/me/taggable_friends` e `/me/invitable_friends` da **API**. Mas como não conheço o seu aplicativo, não sei se encaixa nestas alternativas.